# how to connect to wifi printer from android device?

Tags: android, printing, android-wifi

I want to code a Android app, which will connect to a WIFI printer and print. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wifi is done on a socket but how you print I do not know -- there is some Java stuff on that at a google {P}

Comment: hey thanks .. i want to print pdf or text file after detecting printer on Wifi .. i dont know how to achive this can you please explain steps ..

Comment: @hlb007 can you post your solution ?

Comment: @hlb007 can you post your solutions?